# docker-compose.yml with Ngrok exposing two ports

Tags: docker, docker-compose, ngrok

I am running Docker Desktop with docker-compose.yml file, and I use Ngrok to expose two ports. I use command "docker-compose up -d", however, I only managed to get one port (e.g. 7071) exposed as part of the yml file is below. I don't know how to get more than 1 ports working. Anyone knows hoe to do it.

```
ngrok:
  image: wernight/ngrok:latest
  ports:
    - 4040:4040
  
  environment:
    NGROK_AUTH: 
    NGROK_PROTOCOL: https
    NGROK_PORT: 7071

  networks:
    - default
```